# Как правильно отобразить данные в гистограмме matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Имеется список совершенных действий по часам ( от 00 до 24 ):

```
data = [0, 1068, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 39, 
        77, 100, 135, 94, 51, 55, 67, 62, 89, 93, 67, 0, 0]
```

После выполнения кода:

```
plt.hist(data, bins=24)
plt.show()
```

получаю:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы по иксам были часы, а по игрикам - количество совершенных действий.

Comment: Попробуйте документацию >help(plt.hist)

Comment: Вы уверены, что вам нужна гистограмма, а не стоблчатая диаграмма?

Comment: знаете, вы действительно правы